# Why do these two searches have different default behavior?

Tags: discussion, search

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+ios?sort=unanswered
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/android+ios?tab=newest

The first uses AND and the second uses OR. Obviously, you could qualify them one way or the other. But, it's just a curious inconsistency.

Comment: I looked up "qualify" and found out I've been using it incorrectly.

Comment: How did you conclude this? Both searches currently show question that only have the [tag:android] tag and not [tag:ios], so they must both be using `or`.

Comment: @Mureinik The first search shows "7,046 questions tagged" but both [tag:android] and [tag:ios] have more than that.

Comment: @zenith When I follow the link I get 1,012,678 questions. The second link has 327,418 questions.

Comment: @Mureinik So apparently it has different behavior for different users as well (didn't find anything related in the preferences).

Comment: added sort params for consistency

Comment: I can confirm that for me, the first link is AND (~3k posts), while the second is OR (+~300k).

Answer (score 3):

Your first link is for all questions whch have **android** *and* **ios** in the tags. (Approx 1 million questions for me)

Your second link is for *unanswered* questions which have both **android** and **ios** in the tags. (~300 000 questions). Note that unanswered here means "No accepted or upvoted answer".

Also, I'm on the [New navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing), which may explain the the difference in results for different users.